# ¿Crear automáticamente un nuevo documento html desde fichero php?

Tags: php, html, if

Tengo un formulario html (formulario.html) que pide nombre, apellido, anexo(por poner de ejemplo),
una vez que llenen los campos y enviado, pasa por un fichero php (datos.php), aquí almaceno los datos en distintas variables.

El caso es que no sé como hacer, una vez que recoja los datos que están en if, en el fichero php y luego cree un documento html nuevo con esos datos automaticamente.

Este es el documento datos.php sin el if

```
<?php
    $nombre = strip_tags($_POST['nombre']);
    $apellido = strip_tags($_POST['apellido]);
    $anexo = strip_tags($_POST['anexo]);

    $contenido = "<html><body><h1>Datos</h1><p>$nombre</p><p>$apellido</p></body></html>";

    file_put_contents('datos.html', $contenido); ?>
```

cuando agreso el If dentro de la variable $contenido me genera un error.

```
if (empty($anexo)){}
else
    {
        Telefono: $anexo <br />
    }
```

No se si es posible llegar a incluir el if dentro de la variable, pero si se puede espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por favor describe en palabras los que quieres hacer después de guardar los datos en el archivo php. No es muy clara tu descripción. Según entiendo lo que quieres hacer es mostrar en otra pagina los datos ya guardados, correcto?

Comment: Sí, es guardar los datos recibidos y llevarlos a un html. Por eso uso la variable $contenido para guardar todo lo recibido, pero al incluir el if dentro del $contenido me indica error.

Comment: Hola juan que error es el que te genera, el Telefono es parte de html?

Comment: Hola Sergio, este es el error que me indica. -> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si solo necesitas mostrar los datos, puedes hacerlo sin necesidad del nuevo archivo html, así:

```
$contenido = "<html><body><h1>Datos</h1><p>"+$nombre+"</p><p>"+$apellido+"</p></body></html>";
echo $contenido;
```

Ahora, lo que dices de incluir un ciclo if dentro de una variable no es posible. Debes evaluar el if por fuera y cambiar el valor de la variable luego, por lo que tu código completo quedaría así:

```
<?php
    $nombre = strip_tags($_POST['nombre']);
    $apellido = strip_tags($_POST['apellido']);
    $anexo = strip_tags($_POST['anexo']);

     $contenido = "<html><body><h1>Datos</h1><p>"+$nombre+"</p><p>"+$apellido+"</p>";

    if(!empty($anexo)){
        $contenido = $contenido + "Telefono: "+$anexo+" <br/>";
    }

    $contenido = $contenido+"</body></html>";

    echo $contenido;
?>
```

Comment: Genial !! Lo hice en base a tus comentarios y me resultó. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Con gusto, por favor selecciona mi respuesta como la solución a tu pregunta.

Comment: En las asignaciones si se pueden usar if

Comment: como se podría hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

En las asignaciones puedes usar el operador ternario **?:** para usar condicionales

```
$contenido = sprintf("<html><body><h1>Datos</h1><p>%s</p><p>%s</p>%s</body></html>", $nombre, $apellido, empty($anexo) ? '': 'Telefono: '.$anexo.'<br />');
//De esta manera ahorras unas cuantas lineas (3 exactamente) y hace lo que querias
```

Comment: Mucha gracias! Interesante respuesta

Answer (score 0):

poner codigo html en un controlador PHP es una mala práctica. Partiendo de un patrón estructural MVC pues la vista es la encargada de generar todo lo concerniente a HTML. El controlador responsable de las peticiones http y de gestionar los request and response . Entonces respondiendo ¿como haces para enviar a la vista un pedazo de código HTML que dentro de él se ejecute php? y no incurrir en malas prácticas como la sugerencia anterior. Para eso existe los templates que son pedazos de código html/php en los cuales puedes pasarle variables para contenido dinamico, generalmente esto se hace con un motor de plantilla por ejemplo [smarty](https://www.smarty.net/) , con esto logras evitar escribir HTML directamente en el controlador.(lo cual es una malisima práctica de programación) A continuación te dejo como seria con PHP puro.

**Declaramos la plantilla**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
    // aca puedes ejecutar php como siempre recuerda la $variable debe declararse antes de llamar a la plantilla
    echo $variable;
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Ahora llamas a la plantilla desde el controlador**

```
<?php
  $variable = 'esto se populará en la plantilla';
  ob_start();
  $html = require_once 'template.php';
  $buffer = ob_get_clean();
  //una vez almacenado en la variable $buffer puedes ejecutarlo en cualquier momento posterior a su declaración.
  echo $buffer;
  ?>
```